# How to search for text in a rich text box

Tags: c#, winforms, replace, find, richtextbox

I have this code for finding text in the Rtf box and highlighting the text.

```
public Form1()
{
InitializeComponent();
}
public int currentPos = 1; // this is so currentPos does not loose its value
```

Then I have Three events tied to buttons like this

```
private void button5_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
       
        currentPos = 1;

        if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(this.textBox1.Text))
        {
            if (this.richTextBox1.Text.Contains(this.textBox1.Text) && currentPos < this.richTextBox1.Text.Length)
            {
                if (this.richTextBox1.Text.Substring(currentPos).Contains(this.textBox1.Text))
                {

                    int start = this.richTextBox1.Text.Substring(currentPos).IndexOf(this.textBox1.Text);
                    this.richTextBox1.Select(start + currentPos, this.textBox1.Text.Length);
                    currentPos = start + currentPos + this.textBox1.Text.Length;
                    this.richTextBox1.Focus();
                }
                else
                {
                    //restart the method after resetting the indicator
                    button5.Text = "Find Next";
                    button5_Click(button5, new EventArgs());
                }
            }
            else
            {
                //restart the method after resetting the indicator
                currentPos = currentPos + 1;
                if (this.richTextBox1.Text.Contains(this.textBox1.Text))
                {
                 
                    button5_Click(button5, new EventArgs());
                }
                else
               
                    MessageBox.Show("Text not found");
            }
        }
    
     }

    // same as the previous code for button5_Click except currentPos
    // does not start over, it keeps searching from where it found the
    // last text
    private void button6_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
             if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(this.textBox1.Text))
        {
            if (this.richTextBox1.Text.Contains(this.textBox1.Text) && currentPos < this.richTextBox1.Text.Length)
            {
                if (this.richTextBox1.Text.Substring(currentPos).Contains(this.textBox1.Text))
                {

                    int start = this.richTextBox1.Text.Substring(currentPos).IndexOf(this.textBox1.Text);
                    this.richTextBox1.Select(start + currentPos, this.textBox1.Text.Length);
                    currentPos = start + currentPos + this.textBox1.Text.Length;
                    this.richTextBox1.Focus();
                }
                else
                {
                
                    DialogResult dialogResult = MessageBox.Show( "Larry's Journal has finished searching through the document. Do you want to continue the search from the top of the document?", "Message", MessageBoxButtons.YesNo);
                    if (dialogResult == DialogResult.Yes)
                    {
                        currentPos = 1;

                        button5_Click(button5, new EventArgs());
                    }
                    else if (dialogResult == DialogResult.No)
                    {
                        //do something else
                    }

                }
            }
           else
            {
                //restart the method after resetting the indicator
                currentPos = currentPos + 1;
                if (this.richTextBox1.Text.Contains(this.textBox1.Text))
                    button1_Click(button5, new EventArgs());
                else
                    MessageBox.Show("Text not found");
            }
        }

    }
 // This replaces the selected text in the richtextbox with the contents
 // of texxtBox2 which is the replacement text.
 private void button10_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
       textBox2.SelectAll();
        textBox2.Copy();
        richTextBox1.Paste();
    }
```

The first button5_Click is for Finding the text in the richtextbox.
The second button6_Click is for finding the next instance of that text.
The Third button10_Click is for replacing the text found with some other text
if you so desire. I edited this question to show that I figured out how to do it. It's not the find methods Microsoft talks about in their page on how work with richtextboxes, but it works.

I post this here for any programmer who feels they can use it. Just copy and paste it into your program. All you need is 3 buttons and two textboxes and one richtextbox in addition to whatever other controls you already have in your program.

Comment: Your code is totally incorrect. The RichTextBox has methods to Find text, including versions that let you specify a starting point for the search (which would be how you implement Find Next). See the [documentation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.richtextbox_methods(v=vs.110).aspx). The methods you want are the three overloaded versions of `Find`.

Comment: Thanks , I know that's the right way to go as well, Am editing this comment as I found out where to put it so a not to mess up any other parts of the app, however I still do not know how to call it from my Find button.

Comment: Um... `richTextBox1.Find(textBox1.Text)`? There are examples on each page in multiple languages (including C#). What part of those samples are you having difficulty with?

Comment: At first it was finding where to put it in the code. But I got that figured out. So I tried the richTextBox1.Find(textBox1.Text) and I pressed the find button and it did nothing. My problem was trying to figure out what calls the code I put in off of the documentation you pointed me to. I guess I thought you had to call the FindMyText with the textBox1.Text part in the ()  like it was a method or something.

Comment: `Find` *is* a method of the RichTextBox. It returns an int32 that tells you where the text was found. Did you even look at the documentation that I linked? It tells you **exactly** what it does, **exactly** what it returns when it does (or does not) find the text, and shows you **exact code** that shows how to use it.

Comment: I looked at all of that and copied the code over into my program but  when I tried the Find method it did nothing.

Comment: `Find` returns an int32, which you then use (just like you were using IndexOf before in your code). Find itself doesn't *do* anything; it **finds** text and tells you where it is located. As I asked before, did you **read** the documentation I linked? It shows you exactly how to use Find, and how to use the value it returns to highlight the found text.

Comment: you should post the corrected version as an answer, rather than edit the question, so that it's easier to understand what happened here

Answer (score 3):

```
    public static void Find(RichTextBox rtb, String word, Color color)
    {
        if (word == "")
        {
            return;
        }
        int s_start = rtb.SelectionStart, startIndex = 0, index;
        while ((index = rtb.Text.IndexOf(word, startIndex)) != -1)
        {
            rtb.Select(index, word.Length);
            rtb.SelectionColor = color;
            startIndex = index + word.Length;
        }
        rtb.SelectionStart = 0;
        rtb.SelectionLength = rtb.TextLength;
        rtb.SelectionColor = Color.Black;
    }
```

So, basically, that is the "Finding" or "Searching" method. But, I still haven't shown you how to use it :) Here:

```
    private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Find(richtext, textBox1.Text, Color.Blue);
    }
```

Put your `RichTextBox` in place of the `richtext`, and replace `Color.Blue` with the `Color` of your choice. If your searched text isn't coming from a `TextBox`, then replace the `textBox1.Text` with a different `Control`.

If you end up **not** wanting `Color`, then remove `Color color`, remove `Color.Blue`, and remove `rtb.SelectionColor = color;`

This is all I have on the matter, I hope it helps you :)

Comment: You're reversing your highlighting with he last three lines...

Answer (score 0):

With this code, you can select the text to be searched from the focus start position set by RichTextBox, In addition to providing some search conditions, such as those found in NotePad for Windows

```
private void button1_Click(object Sender, EventArgs e)

    {
        string s1 = textBox1.Text;
        `int` a = richTextBox1.SelectionStart + 1;

        if (radioButton1.Checked == true &&
            (checkBox1.Checked == false && checkBox2.Checked == false))
        {
            `int` `startpos` = richTextBox1.Find(s1.ToCharArray(), a);
            `int` `length` = s1.Length; a = `startpos`;
            richTextBox1.Focus();
            if (`startpos` > -1)
            {
                richTextBox1.Select(`startpos`, textBox1.Text.Length);
            }
            else
            {
                richTextBox1.SelectionStart = 0;
                `MessageBox.Show`("Finish Find" + textBox1.Text, "Info", `MessageBoxButtons.OK`, `MessageBoxIcon.Information`);
            }
        }


        else if (radioButton1.Checked == true && (checkBox1.Checked == true && checkBox2.Checked == true))
        {
            `int` position = richTextBox1.SelectionStart;
            `int` b = richTextBox1.Text.LastIndexOf(s1, position - 1, `StringComparison.CurrentCulture`);
            if (b > -1)
            {
                richTextBox1.Focus();
                richTextBox1.Select(b, s1.Length);
            }
            else
            {
                b = richTextBox1.Text.Length;
                richTextBox1.SelectionStart = richTextBox1.Text.Length - 1;
            }
        }


        else if (radioButton1.Checked == true && (checkBox1.Checked == true && checkBox2.Checked == false))
        {
            `int` position = richTextBox1.SelectionStart;
            `int` b = richTextBox1.Text.LastIndexOf(s1, position - 1, `StringComparison.CurrentCulture`);
            if (b > -1)
            {
                richTextBox1.Focus();
                richTextBox1.Select(b, s1.Length);
            }
            else
            {
                b = richTextBox1.Text.Length;
                `MessageBox.Show`("Finish Find" + textBox1.Text, "Info", `MessageBoxButtons.OK`, `MessageBoxIcon.Information`);
            }
        }


        else if (radioButton1.Checked == true && (checkBox1.Checked == false && checkBox2.Checked == true))
        {
            `int` position = richTextBox1.SelectionStart;
            `int` b = richTextBox1.Text.LastIndexOf(s1, position - 1);
            if (b > -1)
            {
                richTextBox1.Focus();
                richTextBox1.Select(b, s1.Length);
            }
            else
            {
                b = richTextBox1.Text.Length;
                richTextBox1.SelectionStart = richTextBox1.Text.Length - 1;
            }
          `  //int startpos = richTextBox1.Find(textBox1.Text, a + 1, RichTextBoxFinds.WholeWord);
            //int leanth = s1.Length; a = startpos;
            //richTextBox1.Focus();
            //richTextBox1.Select(startpos, textBox1.Text.Length);`
        }

        else if (radioButton2.Checked == true && (checkBox1.Checked == true && checkBox2.Checked == true))
        {
          `  int position = richTextBox1.SelectionStart;
            int b = richTextBox1.Find(s1, position + 1, RichTextBoxFinds.MatchCase);`
            if (b > -1)
            {
                richTextBox1.Focus();
                richTextBox1.Select(b, s1.Length);
            }
            else
            {
                b = richTextBox1.Text.Length;
                richTextBox1.SelectionStart = richTextBox1.Text.Length - 1;
            }
        }
        else if (radioButton2.Checked == true && (checkBox1.Checked == true && checkBox2.Checked == false))
        {
          `  int position = richTextBox1.SelectionStart;
            int b = richTextBox1.Find(s1, position + 1, RichTextBoxFinds.MatchCase);`
            if (b > -1)
            {
                richTextBox1.Focus();
                richTextBox1.Select(b, s1.Length);
            }
            else
            {
                b = richTextBox1.Text.Length;
                Message Box .Show("Finish Find" + textBox1.Text, "Info", Message Box Buttons .OK, Message Box Icon .Information);
            }
        }
        else if (radioButton2.Checked == true && (checkBox1.Checked == false && checkBox2.Checked == true))
        {
            `int` position = richTextBox1.SelectionStart;
            `int` b = richTextBox1.Find(s1, position + 1, Rich Text Box Finds . None);
            if (b > -1)
            {
                richTextBox1.Focus();
                richTextBox1.Select(b, s1.Length);
            }
            else
            {
                b = richTextBox1.Text.Length;
                richTextBox1.SelectionStart = richTextBox1.Text.Length - 1;
            }
        }
    }`
```

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

So, I know this is a very old question, but I thought I would add a modern solution that may help people searching for it:

```
int StartIndex = 0;
/// <summary>Progressive search for text in a RichTextBox, automatically highlight and display results.</summary>
/// <param name="pSearchText">Text to Find</param>
public void FindTextInDocs(string pSearchText)
{
    try
    {
        if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(pSearchText))
        {
            //1. Buscamos en el RTF actual:
            if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(richTextBoxEx1.Text))
            {
                var Options = RichTextBoxFinds.None;
                if (FindMatchCase.Checked) Options |= RichTextBoxFinds.MatchCase;
                if (FindWholeWord.Checked) Options |= RichTextBoxFinds.WholeWord;

                StartIndex = richTextBoxEx1.Find(pSearchText, StartIndex, Options);
                if (StartIndex > 0)
                {
                    StartIndex += pSearchText.Length;
                }
            }
        }
    }
    catch { StartIndex = 0; } //<- Starts from begining on error
}
```

SearchOptions are Checked Menus (or whatever) somewhere in your UI.